# If conciousness isn't physical does it imply god?

Tags: metaphysics, theology, consciousness

Think about it. The brain is designed for consciousness. Physical objects, other ones aren't conscious.

We know because they show no signs of consciousness. They can't move on their own, which is what conscious things do. If our brains are designed for consciousness, but the consciousness isn't physical, and our consciousness needs a cause, the cause isn't anything natural.

However the fact that brains are the things which are tied to consciousness only shows that this implies conscious intent. The universe was also designed in a way that allows life. The fact that the being was able to design our brain shows that it has the capacity to interact with our universe and design things in it, complex things that require high intelligence, sounds like god. If it designed the brain then the natural belief in god can be attributed to it.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147941/discussion-on-question-by-loopit-if-conciousness-isnt-physical-does-it-imply-go); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: "Physical objects, other ones aren't conscious." Actually we know *nothing* about what is not conscious.

Answer (score 2):

> Think about it, the brain is designed for consciousness

Let me stop you right there. The claim "the brain is designed" needs some evidentiary support.

Comment: The evidence is that , your brain still doesn’t account for what it’s like to be concious , it’s just a bunch of physical arrangements , so so isn’t concious , despite it being soemthing that seems to be designed for conciousness , conciousness needs a cause , the cause isn’t physical , nothing natural produced it, the fact that what’s convnietnyl suitable for conciousness is what actually holds concious beings or is controlled by them and by them shows that  this is no coincidence , on top of that our conciousness has all the functions that are supposed to be produced by our brain

Comment: Something this convenient is very unlikely to happen if the natural world meaning the things that aren’t caused by any concious being , are more likely than not to be random events, if someone puts all his time into making a game that is obviously designed for the purposes of killing robbers , then specifically allows robbers to be in the game as well as guns, you can’t claim it is a coincidence , and wasn’t intentional

Comment: As far as I can tell, my consciousness is an emergent property of my brain. If my brain were destroyed, so too would be my consciousness. If I alter my brain, my consciousness changes, too. 

This points to my consciousness being the result of what the physical brain is/does. I'm unaware of any evidence that a consciousness can exist independent of a brain, and I'm unaware of any evidence that a consciousness needs some external (ie. outside the brain) source.

Comment: @microondas I believe, if you consider for a moment, you will wish to amend the parenthetical to (i.e. outside the body).

Comment: @microondas "if my brain is altered conciousness is as well" and you listed other reasons as well, but, the truth is that even if this is the case, find antoehr explanation, if everything in this world needed to be physical explain how conciousness isn't but still works. Consciousness is the field of subjective experience. We can communicate aspects of this experience, but we can never share directly in any consciousness other than our own. so you cna pose alternatives but not stick to this view, realize the brain is a bunch of physical things, arranging it in a certain way wont make conscious

Comment: @loopit How do you know conciousness isnt physical, when we currently dont even physically understand the mind?  This is not something resolved at all, and in philosophy it is still very much debated.

Comment: @JMac come on man, do you really think arranging a bunch of random physical objects will make you conscious

Comment: @JMac the brain doesn't account or likely doesnt account for wha tits actually like to be concious

Comment: @loopit No, I dont think arranging a bunch of _random_ physical objects would create conciousness.  But our brain isnt that "random".  AFAIK all our brains are made out of essentially the same stuff.  And the structure isnt random either, in fact we know it is influenced by experience.  I see it as possibility that our experienced conciousness is explained by physical processes that we dont understand at this point.  Not to say it must be the case, but I dont see how we can rule it out with our current understanding.

Comment: @gs Yes, your correction is a good one--"outside the body" would've been the better phrase for me to use.

Comment: @loopit "the brain is a bunch of physical things, arranging it in a certain way won't make it conscious": as far as I can tell, current evidence shows that in fact, the "arrangement" of those "physical things" DOES make it conscious. When you alter the "physical things", the consciousness is altered. I don't see a reason to point to something beyond the brain/body as a source of consciousness and you haven't given a good one yet.

Comment: @microondas I already told you, your brain doesn't account for what its actually like to be conscious

Comment: @microondas it only seems like it, but the problem here that your assuming the universe has to actually make sense

Comment: @microondas the argument means, not everything in the universe can be explained in an absolutely physical way, consciousness isn't explained in an absolutely physical way, even if there is some type of connection it still doesn't mean anything, there's nothing about the actual brain that should make consciousness happen,

Comment: @loopit "not everything in the universe can be explained in an absolutely physical way". Cool, I think I actually agree with that--there are unexplained things. Can you give an example of something with an accepted non-physical explanation?

Answer (score 0):

You run together a few things here.

1. the **argument from design**
2. an argument that God is anything non-physical that exists before - causes - life: a bit like the **cosmological argument** except the business of a physical  universe is irrelevant/bypassed because it does not feature in your explanation, either as explanans or explanandum.

Both arguments themselves have a long history.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_consciousness

May help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are onto something... The fact that we are conscious implies not just the existence of God alone, but also that of the Devil, and of the tooth fairy and Santa Claus, of Zeus and Hera and their olympian clique, of Isis and Osiris, of Ganesh, Shiva and Vishnu, etc. etc. etc. ;-)

Comment: I have many other arguments, this actually leads to god, this doesn't prove god but leads to it, we know the creator of the brain is conscious

Comment: @loopit There could be many creators, not just one.

Comment: by leading to god I mean it , with other arguments can lead to god